# Meteor (0.9.0.1): Using Helper with autoform to update a record for multiple users

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm in the process of building my admin area.  I thought it would be useful to have multiple admin users each with access to the same data.  I'm using this [roles package](http://atmospherejs.com/digilord/roles).

I am using autoform to generate the form so when logged in as 'AdminA', this user enters a value in the form and submits it, the record is then stored under AdminA's account.  AdminB then logs in but doesn't see the value on the form because this user doesn't have access to AdminA's account.  I need a way of telling autoform to update the one record.

The code below is what I'm trying to achieve.  Can anyone suggest what I need to do to get this to work?  I've had a look at the autoform docs and I'm not entirely sure.

The form input box would look a bit like this when rendered:

```
<input type="text" name="VehiclePrice" value="10000" />
<input type="hidden" name="_id" value="LEXANiNZtunFPfBea">
```

Template:

```
<template name="VehiclePrice">
 {{#if submitted}}
    {{> quickForm collection="VehiclePrice" omitFields="createdBy" doc=editingDoc id="VehiclePrice" type="update"}}
 {{else}}
    {{> quickForm collection="VehiclePrice" omitFields="createdBy" id="VehiclePrice" type="insert"}}
 {{/if}}
</template>
```

Helper:

```
Template.VehiclePrice.helpers({ 
 VehiclePrices: function () {
   return VehiclePrice.find().map(function (c) {
     return {price: c.price, _id: c._id};
   });
 }
});
```

The relationship would be many admin users to one record (*:1)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

By publishing the vehicle collection, you can, programatically, determine who has access to the data, and what data set is published.  Take a look at the Meteor publish documentation (http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish).

After setting up your collection, you can determine what data sets get published through the publish command with something like:

`Meteor.publish("vehicleInfo", function () {
  if ( this.role == "admin" ) 
    return Vehicle.find();
  else 
    return Vehicle.find({some subset of the data, or none at all (false)});
});`

Comment: I've updated the question, I don't think I'm being clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, this was an issue with one of my helpers.  It was limiting data by the user, I ammended that and it worked fine.